# Proper python default variable initialization

Tags: python, initialization

I have inherited some python code that I'm trying to clean up.

There were no type hints and for all classes it starts by initializing all members to None.

I have added type hints where I could; Like e.g.:

```
class MyData:
    Data: dict = None
    Source: int = None
    DataType: str = None
    ReceiverType: str = None
```

However it seems 'wrong' to assign `None` to all the members (MyPy also complains quite a lot).

**What is the proper way to initialize variables and class members in Python?**

Comment: `typing.Optional[type]`, it is worth noting that this will not initialize the members of the instance, they are all class attributes.

Comment: You just want me to be aware of this? Or would you care to elaborate in a way which may help me answer my query?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyData:
    Data: dict = {}
    Source: int = 0
    DataType: str = ""
    ReceiverType: str = ""
```

If you change your code to the above, does MyPy complain? I think setting all your attributes to the initial value of None (aka null) does not make sense if they are never used.

Comment: These are actual valid values, so that won't work. The None assignment signifies that the members are not initialized, where as an empty string easily could be a valid string you'd assign to a variable.
I need something safe to replace None with, that still makes sense as a placeholder for "null".

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for exists in Python. It's either this or use `None`

Comment: Still hoping for a nice solution to this.. but so far been unable to find it by myself